# Mailchimp DATE Merge Tag in URL updating after email sent

Tags: email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am utilizing a Mailchimp *|DATE:|* [merge tag](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/merge-tags/basic-merge-tags/) in a URL, and I have click-tracking enabled on my campaign. The problem is that Mailchimp is updating the date in the URL each day rather than keeping it fixed on the date that the email was sent. Is there any way I can fix this without disabling click tracking?

Here is an example URL I created with the *|DATE:mdY|* merge tag:

```
http://example.com/abc?dt_sent=*|DATE:mdY|*
```

If that email was sent on February 7th, 2019, the URL would initially be this:

```
http://example.com/abc?dt_sent=02072019
```

But on February 8th, 2019, the URL would change in the email that was sent the day prior to this:

```
http://example.com/abc?dt_sent=02082019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailchimp customer service gave the following feedback when asked why merge tags in links that had click tracking enabled were updating after an email was sent, while merge tags in links that did not have click tracking enabled were not updating after an email was sent:

> Right, that's expected. Because the link comes to us, we do that lookup, the current information is used, then they get forwarded. I do
>   understand where you're coming from, though, and can pass along this
>   feedback to our developers.